# TL-R860 v5 can't ignor or forbid ping packets

Tags: router, ping

Although I checked both "Ignore Ping Packet From WAN Port" and "Forbid Ping Packet From LAN Port" and rebooted the router, my TL-R860 v5 (Firmware Version: 4.8.3 Build 120308 Rel.37973n) still replies to ping requests both from WAN and LAN.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to stop it?

[image: TL-R860 v5 Advanced Security]

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer***I'm not 100% sure on this, it's just my two cents ***Disclaimer***

You're probably pinging your inside ports. Ipconfig/all on one of your networks, and check your default gate. If you're pinging your default gate it's going to go through unless you SERIOUSLY want to secure your network.

Type in tracert 8.8.8.8 in cmd

That's google's DNS server. Whatever your second hop is should be your external ip address. I'm 99% sure this is what you have secured from lan/wan pings. Usually routers apply ACL's to their outbound ports. Regular homeowner routers won't even give the option to write an ACL on your default gate side.

It's been awhile since i've messed around with outbound/inbound and it's 1am so I think i'm mixing the two up, but the point applies still. I'd recommend trying what I suggested as a further diagnostic test.

If that doesn't work, make sure to comment it so I know.

*Edited this for grammar*

Comment: I'm pinging my IP from an external site...

Comment: Well shoot. I was hoping that was the problem. Can you ping your networks default gate from the outside? Or within the network?

Comment: I have these same settings on my TP-Link Archer C8 (v1 Firmware), and I just tested. Sorry to say it all works fine. If I ping my Public IP from Cellular data with 'Ignore WAN' option checked, sure enough, it ignores it. I can even uncheck it as the ping command is retrying from Termux on my phone over cell data, and then it stops ignoring and responds as permitted. Same for 'Forbid LAN' ping option, except naturally pinging my public IP from within my private net. Interestingly this is all within the DDOS security settings, so do you have them turned on correctly?